# Куда ставить ударение в слове «некролог»?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: некрОлог или некролОг?

Answer (score 3):

Куда ставить ударение, можно узнать **по словарям на Грамоте.ру**

**НекролОг**, -а; м. [от греч. nekrós — мёртвый и **lógos — слово**] Статья по поводу смерти кого-л. с сообщением сведений о жизни и деятельности умершего. Напечатать н. в газете. Н. подписали деятели культуры.

**Главной** является вторая часть (lógos — слово).

Однако в стихах можно встретить другое ударение (В. Высоцкий):

*И хоть путь мой и длинен и долог,*
*И хоть я заслужил похвалу —*
**Обо мне не напишут некрОлог**
*На последней странице в углу.*

Но это всего лишь **поэтическая вольность**.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке ударение может падать на любой слог в слове, кроме того, в разных формах одного и того же слова оно иногда перемещается с одной морфемы на другую. Сравните слова: торт – [тОрты](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/torty), кран – крАны (статичное ударение), но бородА – бОроду, карандАш – карандашА (подвижное ударение). При этом никакими правилами нормы не регулируются, произношение следует просто запомнить.

Слову **«некролог»** повезло больше. Для него и подобных заимствованных из греческого языка слов, оканчивающихся на -ЛОГ, есть правило, которое регламентирует постановку ударения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Правило:** В словах, которые обозначают профессии, на греческий корень -ЛОГ ударение не будет падать: биОлог, филОлог, стоматОлог. **В неодушевленных существительных -ЛОГ становится ударным: каталОг, эпилОг.**

[Куда ставить ударение в слове «некролог»?](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/nekrolog)

Comment: А в слове анАлог  какой корень, разве не греческий? А ударение на основе.